# Conio2.h in CodeBlocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

first I want to apologize for my bad English and second for this topic, I didnt find anything like this so I create it.

My problem is:
I want to create a game where I want to use conio2.h, but problem is, that I cant find it on the internet. Still I find something with Linux, but I need it on windows. Im using CodeBlocks, it is good program but it doesnt have this library

Can you help me guys?

Answer (score 1):

Conio is an old MS-DOS header. You will not find it in modern compilers. For Unix/Linux systems, you can use [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29), Windows Systems have their own libraries and functions.

You may want to ask a question on how to do something specific you are having problems with and posting some code.

For example, setting the cursor position can be done with [SetConsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

Comment: I want to create a game where will be enemy and you, and your goal is, kill as many enemy as is possible, so I need create moving for your ship and for enemy and SetConsoleCursorPosition isnt good idea

Comment: That sounds like you should use a graphic library, not a console.

Comment: Your ship will be looks like "@" for example and enemies for example "#" something simple for project to the school.